# Allow transparent port forwarding in Azure subnet

Tags: routing, azure, port-forwarding, virtual-network

I have a VM in an Azure VNet that needs to know the original public IP address of incoming connections that are port forwarded by a firewall appliance. 
So far I can only successfully port forward from the firewall to the server if I "SNAT" the incoming connection. But that hides the original source IP.

Here is a simplification of the
[current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeI6A.jpg)

Firewall has single interface of 10.0.0.1 which is associated with a public IP in Azure. Port forwarding is configured on firewall to send any TCP 80 to server 10.0.1.1 following logic as outlined in this [blog](https://www.opsgility.com/blog/2016/07/14/rethinking-paradigms-in-networking-firewalls-in-the-public-cloud/)
Client connects to public IP address. Logs on firewall show approved data from IP 1.2.3.4 -> 10.0.0.1. If outbound NAT is configured on the firewall to translate the connection after port forwarding, the server (10.0.1.1) shows the connection, but the source IP = 10.0.0.1 (ie the private interface of the FW)

If outbound NAT translation is disabled on the FW appliance, the logs show the same approved information on the FW for an incoming connection, but the packet never reaches the 10.0.1.1 sever.

If I stand up a second server 10.0.1.2 or 10.0.0.2 and then connect to 10.0.0.1:80 (with outbound NAT translation disabled on the FW appliance) then the connection makes it successfully though to to server 10.0.1.1 and the src IP correctly equals 10.0.1.2 or 10.0.0.2

I suspect the Azure fabric routing is dropping any packets where any src IP is not within the range of the VNet address space. 
There are plenty of online articles showing a similar "DMZ" style approach like this in Azure, but none where the request handling servers need to know the original public source IP address.

Can it be done ?

**Edit:**

After fighting with this all day I could not get it to work. So I've dropped the FW and recreated another applicance with 2 NICs. The original NIC (the WAN) as it was before and the other in the 10.0.1.1 subnet (the LAN). BUT IT STILL FAILS TO WORK! I cant even get a connection...

I have a replicated the same setup in my office on some bare metal and it works perfectly. I've checked all the FW settings (including routes) between the bare metal instance and the azure instance. I've run a packet capture on the LAN interface of the azure instance and can see the "port forwarded" packets leaving the interface. I have Wireshark running on 10.0.1.1 but no packets ever arrive!
I thought it might be a default gateway problem so I added a user defined route to the 10.0.1.0 subnet for network 1.2.3.4/32 to make sure the ACK's would return to the client via the FW appliance. But that did not work either.

Any other help would be very much appreciated, this one has be busted.

**Success**

Many hours and VM's later I've got it to work. The problem was the user defined route on the 10.0.1.x network. I had only enabled a route to cover the range of the clients connecting but that did not work. If I set the UDR = 0.0.0.0/0 and next hop to the FW appliance, then bingo.

So to summise my working config.

- pfSense firewall with one NIC
- NIC in 10.0.0.x network with public IP also associated
- No outbound NAT mappings defined
- Port forward rule from client IP:port to server in 10.0.1.x network
- User defined rule of 0.0.0.0/0 set on 10.0.1.x network with next hop = private ip of NIC on FW
- IP forwarding enabled on the FW NIC

Whilst the above now passes the client IP all the way through to the VM in the 10.0.1.x network and allows a successful connection, I did add an outbound NAT mapping of 10.0.1.x/24 so the VM can access the internet. Without it, it could not.
The UDR also kills any access via a public IP attached to the VM in the 10.0.1.x network and additional rules are now needed on the FW to allow RDP etc to the VM via the FW.

For anyone's benefit, I also got the two NIC FW working too. Here the UDR just needs to point to the IP of the 'LAN' NIC.

Comment: You keep saying "firewall" but make no mention of what firewall you are running, it sounds like y ou mean a separate hardware firewall rather than the functionality built into Azure, but we need to know. Also is this using the ASM or ARM stack?

Comment: Yes by word "Appliance" in the picture I meant a specific firewall on top of the firewalling and routing functions of the fabric. I did not specifically mention the make of the firewall because my testing suggests the firewall is not the issue and I wanted to keep readers focused on the issue. The actual firewall I'm using is pfSense, but my guess is that if that any other firewall was used the same issue would arise. All components are on the ARM stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If outbound NAT is configured on the firewall to translate the connection after port forwarding, the server (10.0.1.1) shows the connection, but the source IP = 10.0.0.1 (ie the private interface of the FW)
>
> If outbound NAT translation is disabled on the FW appliance, the logs show the same approved information on the FW for an incoming connection, but the packet never reaches the 10.0.1.1 sever.

All of these are by design behavior. And it should work in this way.

If the source IP address is not the private address of the firewall, then the response will be sent to the 1.2.3.4 directly.(The source IP is a public IP address and the response will be sent with the public address assigned to the server.)

The client which sends the packet will get a response from a totally different public IP address, which will cause the connection failure.

To make the response packets going through the firewall, the outbound NAT should be enabled.

=========================================================================

Update:

If the User Defined Route (UDR) is involved, then it works. I tested it with 2 Linux VMs.

Several points need noticing:

1. The IP forwarding should be enabled on the VM which performs the port forwarding.(Both of the settings on Azure portal and OS.)
2. The NSG of the VM which performs the port forwarding need reconfiguring to allow the forwarded traffic and the response from the client VM.
3. The NSG of the client VM need reconfiguring to allow the traffic forwarded by the port forwarding VM.

Comment: Steven yes I agree, but what if a user defined route exists on the 10.0.1.x network to push traffic via the 10.0.0.1 appliance, wont the client see the response coming from the public IP ? Also see my update in my question, any ideas welcome.

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange I've tested it in my lab. If the UDR is involved, the port forwarding works. I've updated my answer to append that part.

Comment: I've updated my question with the configuration that I got to work. It does not match the settings you outlined. I have not tested your config but if you say it works then I suppose that qualifies as an answer too.